# Localize properties during serialization with JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization, task

As far as I understand, `AsyncLocal` gives the capability to persist its value across tasks, so I would expect the following example code to persist the `Context.Culture` value when the object is being serialized, it's not.

It seems to me that given the `PropertyDisplay.Text` has a getting, it's being executed "differently" such that the value of `Context.Culture` gets lost.

Is my assumption correct?
If not, is there a way to accomplish this?

Expected output

```
{
  "text": "prefix-zh-CHS"
}
```

Actual output

```
{
  "text": "prefix"
}
```

Sample code:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> LanguageMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    { "zh", "zh-CHS" }
};

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    PropertyDisplay propertyDisplay = null;
    string json = null;
    ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Context.Culture = GetCultureInfo("zh");
    });

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        propertyDisplay = new PropertyDisplay()
        {
            Text = "prefix"
        };
    });

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertyDisplay, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            
        });
    });

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static CultureInfo GetCultureInfo(string language)
{
    CultureInfo retVal;

    if (language != null && LanguageMapping.ContainsKey(language))
    {
        language = LanguageMapping[language];
    }

    try
    {
        retVal = new CultureInfo(language);
    }
    catch
    {
        retVal = new CultureInfo("en-us");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

```
public static class Context
{
    private static AsyncLocal<CultureInfo> culture = new AsyncLocal<CultureInfo>();
    
    public static CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get
        {
            return culture?.Value;
        }
    
        set
        {
            culture.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class PropertyDisplay
{
    private string displaySelectionText;
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.displaySelectionText))
            {
                return null;
            }
            
            var localized = GetLocalizedString(this.displaySelectionText);
            return localized;
        }
    
        set
        {
            this.displaySelectionText = value;
        }
    }
    
    public static string GetLocalizedString(string configText)
    {
        string retVal = configText;
        if (Context.Culture != null)
        {
            retVal = $"{configText}-{Context.Culture}";
        }
    
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like if I call
`ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()` then
it persists the value and works as expected.

Wondering if someone can explain how that works.

Comment: `AsyncLocal.Value` is actually stored in the `ExecutionContext` (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2d80343c0f0d8c800045b55fe00b37cbe1279dcd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/AsyncLocal.cs#L60). I'm not sure if `Task.Run` clones the `ExecutionContext`?

Comment: Could you please share with us the updated code where are making use of the `SuppressFlow()`? Please bear in mind that there is a `RestoreFlow` method as well, which could be called only from the same thread from which the `SuppressFlow` method has been called.

Comment: But quite frankly, I don't understand why do you use `AsyncLocal` at all. `AsyncLocal` means (more or less) that each and every async context will see its own local version of the same variable. But you are trying to use it as shared resource between them.

Comment: If you want to set the `CultureInfo` on a different Task than from which do you want to retrieve that then forget `AsyncLocal`. Use it as a "normal" shared resource.

Comment: @HoBa your *real* question is how to localize text properties during serialization, not how to serialize an `AsyncLocal` *field*. Besides, your `PropertyValue` doesn't have any any `AsyncLocal` fields. The current Culture already flows from task to task if you use `async/await`. `AsyncLocal` does the *opposite* of what you ask.

Comment: @PeterCsala Updated the code where I added `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()`. btw, you're correct, I'm trying to share across tasks, the context behind this code is that is an api being selfhosted, and the `Context` class is a test hook to replace `HttpContext.Current.Items`. I also tried `[ThreadStatic]` and didn't work.

The issue is that serialization happens after the controller's task is completed, so it looses its execution context. Refactoring serialization/localization is not an option :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `AsyncLocal` or `ThreadStatic` or anything special at all.

All you need is to capture the `Context` in the right moment and pass it to the `PropertyDisplay`.

Here is the simplified `Context` class (nothing fancy needed):

```
public class Context
{
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
}
```

Rather than making it `static` you should create a new instance each and every time.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = new Context();
    await Task.Run(() => context.Culture = GetCultureInfo("zh"));

    PropertyDisplay propertyDisplay = null;
    await Task.Run(() => propertyDisplay = new PropertyDisplay(context) { Text = "prefix" });

    string json = null;
    await Task.Run(() => json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertyDisplay, Formatting.Indented));

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You also need to do some changes on the `PropertyDisplay` class to receive a `Context` instance:

```
public class PropertyDisplay
{
    private string displaySelectionText;
    private readonly Context context;
    public PropertyDisplay(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...

    public string GetLocalizedString(string configText)
    {
        if (context.Culture == null) return configText;
        return $"{configText}-{context.Culture}";
    }
}
```

Or you can further simplify the `GetLocalizedString` to be a one-liner:

```
public string GetLocalizedString(string configText)
    => configText + context.Culture != null ? $"-{context.Culture}" : "";
```

And that's it. The output will be as expected:

```json
{
  "text": "prefix-zh-CHS"
}
```